# excel vba object-defined error

Tags: vba, excel

I am learning excel vba and I´m stuck with this error for a few hours. I´ve read some solutions here but I can´t fix it. This code gets a photo path and inserts the photo in comment-box of cell A1

```
Sub test()
    Dim TheFile As String
    TheFile = Cells(2, 14).Value

    Range("A1").AddComment
    Range("A1").Comment.Shape.Fill.UserPicture TheFile

End Sub
```

This has application defined or object defined error. I check "TheFile", it returns the correct string which is the file path

Comment: your code works for me as long as `TheFile` has the full path _and_ name of the picture

Comment: yes, if I paste in a string instead of taking path from the cell value. it works

Comment: Have you tried adding `Range("A1").Comment.Visible = True` Between the `Range("A1").AddComment` and the `Range("A1").Comment.Shape.Fill.UserPicture TheFile`  ?

Comment: you may try `TheFile = Cells(2, 14).Value2` and ... check for that cell actual content to be the correct path&name file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you need to use brackets, or the error occurs on adding a comment althoug there alredy is a comment

```
Sub test()
    Dim TheFile As String
    TheFile = Cells(2, 14).Value

    'Only adds a comment if cell don´t already have one
    If Range("A1").Comment Is Nothing Then Range("A1").AddComment           
    Range("A1").Comment.Shape.Fill.UserPicture (TheFile)
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you try adding the If-Statement i write befor adding a comment? `If Range("A1").Comment Is Nothing Then Range("A1").AddComment`

Comment: For me the code perfectly works. Are you sure your taking the path from the right cell? Cells(2, 14) is Cell N2

Comment: yes, I used msgbox to check if i got the correct path.

Comment: osssp, i got. u're correct. thanks. If Range("A1").Comment Is Nothing Then Range("A1").AddComment

Comment: No problem :) would you just mark the anser as correct please?